# Spring batch keeps running

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I have a Spring batch project using SpringBoot where I have created the Configuration class. I have used and implemented `ItemReader`, `ItemProcessor` and `ItemWriter` interfaces for the sep.

Below is the `ItemReader` implementation. The `ItemReader` implementation reads data from a JSON file ( `test-data.json` ) and converts it into a Java object i.e. `ItemsData`. The issue is when I am starting my spring boot application,

the spring batch job keeps running in an infinite loop and never stops. I read some documentation and it says that unless and until the `ItemReader` is not returning a `null`, it will keep on running the spring batch job. So I am wondering how to fix this issue and make the batch job run only 1 time per `scheduled time.

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class ItemsReader implements ItemReader<ItemsData> {
    

    @Override
    public ItemsData read() throws Exception, UnexpectedInputException, ParseException, NonTransientResourceException {

            Gson gson = new Gson();
            Reader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("./src/main/resources/test-data.json"));
            ItemsData itemsData = new Gson().fromJson(reader, new TypeToken<ItemsData>() {}.getType());
            reader.close();
            log.info("**************** Items read for processing");
            
            return itemsData;
       
    }
}
```

Comment: Return `null` when finished. Looks like you don't understand what an `ItemReader` does. I suspect you read this file once, and that your `ItemProcessor` is being used to split it. Don't. Let the `ItemReader` read individual elements and when finished return `null`.

Comment: +1 to what @M.Deinum said. From the Javadoc of [ItemReader](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.3.x/api/org/springframework/batch/item/ItemReader.html): `Implementations are expected to be [..] returning null when all input data is exhausted.`

Comment: I found the solution. Here is the updated code :

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution. Here is the updated code :

```
@StepScope
@Component
@Slf4j
public class ItemsReader implements ItemReader<ItemsData> {
    private ItemReader<ItemsData> delegate;

    @Override
    public ItemsData read() throws Exception, UnexpectedInputException, ParseException, NonTransientResourceException {
        System.out.println("+++++++++++++++++++ in items read class, delegate value "+delegate);
        if (delegate == null) {
            System.out.println("+++++++++++++++++++ in items read class IF ");
            List<ItemsData> data = new ArrayList<>();
            data.add(readItemsData());
            delegate = new IteratorItemReader<ItemsData>(data);

        }
        return delegate.read();
    }

    private ItemsData readItemsData() throws IOException {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Reader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("./src/main/resources/test-data.json"));
        ItemsData itemsData = new Gson().fromJson(reader, new TypeToken<ItemsData>() {}.getType());
        reader.close();
        return itemsData;
    }
}
```

Annotating the class with @StepScope and maintaining the state of the ItemsData object did the trick.